# Scala For loop order 2 flatmap

Tags: scala, for-loop, flatmap

I am using for .. yield in scala for looping over objects of type `Future[Try[A]]`. The for .. yield implementation in scala will allow me to flatmap over the outer container(Future) in one for loop and inner container(Try) in a nested loop.

```
for {_a <- a
    _b <- b
} yield {
    for {__a <- _a
        __b <- _b
    } yield {
        someOP(__a, __b)
    }
}
```

I was looking for a way to write this in a single for loop, maybe something like

```
for (__a <- a
     __b <- b
) yield {
    someOP(__a, __b)
}
```

or maybe some sort of traverse function with following method signature:

```
def traverse[G[_], F[_], A](z: F[G[List[A]]])(l: List[F[G[A]]]): F[G[List[A]]]
```

I do realize that if I say type of `F` as `Future` and type of `G` as `Try`, then I can simply write a method that fulfils my requirement. But I was searching for a generic method with could say work with `Option` and `Either` or similar with `flatMap` operation defined in their class like how yield works

Answer (score 1):

So you can't mix monadic contexts in a for comprehension.

You could try Scalaz monad transformers.

[Scalaz monad transformers](https://www.47deg.com/blog/fp-for-the-average-joe-part-2-scalaz-monad-transformers/)

Comment: This looks almost like a link-only answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more, and provide an actual solution that solves the concrete problem?